# Catching error when URL param does not match regex in Express

Tags: node.js, express

I have some code below:

```
app.get('/tx/:txhash([a-zA-Z0-9]{20,50})', (req, res) => {
  //do some work
}
```

My issue is if the parameter does not match the regex pattern, I get

```
Cannot GET /tx/8241fesf
```

But I'm not sure how to have a custom error or redirect. I tried to read the res object but it seems it's skipped altogether and haven't found the answer searching on SO.

Comment: did you try to catch it with another pattern? like:
 `app.get('/tx/:txhash', (req, res) => {/*something for invalid requests}`  or `app.get('/tx/*', (req, res) => {/*something for invalid requests}` ??

Comment: @AsharDweedar Feels like there should be a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle 404 withing express handlers.

In your main express file(may be index.js or app.js) just put following after your routing middleware.

```
app.use("/", your_router);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use((request, response, next) => {
  // Access response variable and handle it
  // response.status(404).send("Your page is not found"))
  // or
  // res.render("home")
});
```

Comment: app.use("/", your_router); is deprecated apparently but otherwise good, thanks.